# Allow ANY website to use my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, web, any

Facebook is telling me that: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

I want to be able to allow any website to use my Facebook app, is that possible?

And if not... is it at least possible, to allow multiple websites to use my app? I operate several websites that will all use the same features...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. In case of Facebook tab/app, the content is pulled from the given URL, so only 1 URL per app is possible. In case of simple website with Facebook login, it's not possible for security reasons.